# If we have 6 balls, 2 yellow, 3 red and 1 green; what are the probabilities of drawing 2 yellow balls in 2 attempts?

Tags: probability

If we have 6 balls, 2 yellow, 3 red and 1 green.

What are the probabilities of drawing 2 yellow balls in 2 goes?
My answer is 1st go is 1/6. Because of no replacement,  2nd go is 1/5. Now do I add the two or multiply the two.  Add gives 11/30, and multiply gives 1/30

Comment: not quite the 1st go is $2/6=1/3$ since there are $2$ yellow balls.

Comment: $\frac{\binom22}{\binom62}=\frac{1}{15}$

Answer (score 1):

Neither answer is correct, but the idea behind your second approach (multiplying) is correct.  The correct answer then is $\frac{1}{15}=\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{5}$.  When you first pick a yellow ball, the probability of grabbing one is $\frac{1}{3}$, while the second time it is $\frac{1}{5}$.  An easy way (in this case) to verify that $\frac{1}{15}$ is correct is to write out all the possibilities.  There are 15 of them, one of which is YY.

Comment: When to use multiply, when to use add?  I am still not very sure.

Answer (score 0):

As MaliciousMalus pointed out, your probability for the first ball being yellow is incorrect. However, to answer the more generic question you pose about adding or multiplying: in a nutshell, you multiply two probabilities whenever you want the probability of both of the events happening (logical and), and add the probabilities when you want the probability of at least one of the events happening (logical or). In the latter case you must also subtract the probability of both events happening, because otherwise that'd be included twice.

In this particular example you want the probability of picking two yellow balls. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ denote the first and second balls being yellow, respectively. Since you want both $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be true, we multiply the probabilities of the first ball being yellow and the probability of the second ball being yellow if the first ball was yellow: $P(Y_1 \cap Y_2) = P(Y_1) \times P(Y_2 | Y_1) = \frac{2}{6} \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$

Comment: This is what I think, please correct me if I am not right.

The probability being a fraction between 0 and 1 is because we are counting the number of favourable outcomes as the numerator and the total possible outcomes as the denominator.

And drawing a yellow ball is 2/6 is because the first ball being yellow is 1/6 or the other yellow ball is drawn, since they are different so the each drawn is mutually exclusive, so we have 1/6 + 1/6 and we get 2/6.

Without replacement, the only occurrence of the remaining yellow ball is the only one so it is 1 / 5.

Comment: Because the favourable event being considered is 2 yellow balls at the same time, so they are multiplied to get 2/6 X 1/5. 

Is my above explanations correct?

Comment: @user256670 Yes, that's it. For the first ball, you have two favorable outcomes out of six, and for the second one, one out of five (since one yellow ball has been removed at this point).